# workflow manager backend service automatically stops

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

**workflow manager backend service** works properly before after updating the credentials its created the issue.

The issue is **workflow manager backend service** is automatically stops

In my local machine password will expire for every 45 days, this is the reason for updated the password in the services. I am stuck over here.

I checked the event logs, its gives me

eventviewer -> windows logs -> application (two errors)

**Log Name:      Application  

Source:        Application Error 

Date:          10/14/2016 12:57:45 PM 

Event ID:      1000 

Task Category: (100) 

Level:         Error 

Keywords:      Classic 

User:          N/A 

Description: 

Faulting application name: Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost.exe, version: 1.0.20922.0, time stamp: 0x505e1b24 

Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.23539, time stamp: 0x57c99bd4 

Exception code: 0xe0434352 

Fault offset: 0x000000000001a06d 

Faulting process id: 0x25f8 

Faulting application start time: 0x01d225ec6be601b8 

Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Workflow Manager\1.0\Workflow\Artifacts\Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost.exe 

Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll 

Report Id: b2875a17-91df-11e6-98e1-d4bed9bae812**

Next one

**Log Name:      Application 

Source:        .NET Runtime 

Date:          10/14/2016 12:57:44 PM 

Event ID:      1026 

Task Category: None 

Level:         Error 

Keywords:      Classic 

User:          N/A 

Description: 

Application: Microsoft.Workflow.ServiceHost.exe 

Framework Version: v4.0.30319 

Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. 

Exception Info: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.GetExistingObject(System.String, System.Type, System.String, System.String) 

   at DynamicClass.ReadVariable.VariableLocationOfstringk9wYX3t0FromXml(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[], System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[]) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.Type, System.String, System.String) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle, System.String, System.String) 

   at DynamicClass.ReadArrayOfLocationFromXml(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString, System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.Type, System.String, System.String) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle, System.String, System.String) 

   at DynamicClass.ReadLocationEnvironmentFromXml(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[], System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[]) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.Type, System.String, System.String) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle, System.String, System.String) 

   at DynamicClass.ReadActivityInstanceFromXml(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[], System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[]) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.Type, System.String, System.String) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle, System.String, System.String) 

   at DynamicClass.ReadActivityInstance.ChildListFromXml(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[], System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[]) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.Type, System.String, System.String) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle, System.String, System.String) 

   at DynamicClass.ReadActivityInstanceFromXml(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[], System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[]) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.Type, System.String, System.String) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle, System.String, System.String) 

   at DynamicClass.ReadActivityInstanceMap.InstanceListFromXml(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[], System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[]) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.Type, System.String, System.String) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle, System.String, System.String) 

   at DynamicClass.ReadArrayOfActivityInstanceMap.InstanceListFromXml(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString, System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.Type, System.String, System.String) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle, System.String, System.String) 

   at DynamicClass.ReadInstanceMapFromXml(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[], System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[]) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.Type, System.String, System.String) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle, System.String, System.String) 

   at DynamicClass.ReadExecutorFromXml(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[], System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[]) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.Type, System.String, System.String) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.RuntimeTypeHandle, System.String, System.String) 

   at DynamicClass.ReadWorkflowSessionStateFromXml(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext, System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[], System.Xml.XmlDictionaryString[]) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Int32, System.Type, System.String, System.String) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, System.Type, System.String, System.String) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Boolean) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlReaderDelegator, Boolean, System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractResolver) 

   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader) 

   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.WorkflowSessionSerializer.DeserializeWorkflowSessionState(System.IO.Stream) 

   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.SessionAccepted(System.IAsyncResult) 

   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.Isolate(AsyncCompletion, System.IAsyncResult) 

   at Microsoft.Activities.Dispatcher.DispatchLoopInstanceAsyncResult.ExceptionHandlingFrame(System.IAsyncResult)**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with the Serialisation of the workflow to or from the Persistence database.
You mention changed credentials.  Perhaps your database is not set up with these new credentials?

Comment: Credentials are not stored in the persistence database.

Comment: Let me rephrase:  Perhaps your application is no longer able to communicate with your persistence database because you have changed the credentials under which the application runs and those credentials do not have sufficient rights to use the persistence database.

Comment: I have checked, workflow manager uses the Integrated Security=True for the WFResourceManagementDB and WFInstanceManagementDB. I am not able to find the where it uses the credentials.

Comment: I am guessing you got "Integrated Security=True" from app.config?
Have you used SQL Management Studio (or what tools you have) to check that these databases are set up to allow access from the user?

Comment: "Integrated Security=True" from web.config. The user have access to the database. I am not able to find the clue so finally reinstalled the workflow to move to next work. Very much thanks for the reply.